# Using covariant return type while overriding method from granparent interface results in complier error

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, covariance, covariant-return-types

```
public interface EntityId {
...
    EntityId cloneWithNewId(long id);
}
```

```
public interface Ticket extends EntityId {
/// cloneWithNewId - is not mentioned in this interface
}
```

```
public record TicketImpl(...)
@Override
    public Ticket cloneWithNewId(long id) {...}
```

The compiler gives the error, when I write in my unit test the line with "cloneWithNewId" call:

```
    @Test
    void shouldBookTicket() {
        Ticket ticket = new TicketImpl(7L, 8L, Ticket.Category.PREMIUM, 21);
        Ticket expectedTicket = ticket.cloneWithNewId(1L); // compiler error in this line
    //...
    }
```

"EntityId cannot be converted to Ticket. Required type:
Ticket. Provided: EntityId"

Any ideas why? Seems to be not much different from classic examples for covariant return type.

It works if I make EnityId interface generic

```
public interface EntityId<? extends T> {
...
    T cloneWithNewId(long id);
}
```

```
public interface Ticket extends EntityId<Ticket> {
/// cloneWithNewId - is not mentioned in this interface
}
```

It also works if I add the method declaration to Ticket interface:

```
public interface Ticket extends EntityId {
    Ticket cloneWithNewId(long id);
}
```

But I do not understand, why it does not work when I override method from extended interface.

Comment: There is no covariance here. If `Ticket` had `Ticket cloneWithNewId(long id)`, or `TicketImpl` had `TicketImpl cloneWithNewId(long id)`, that would be covariance. Not this.

Comment: What is the declared type of `ticket` in `Ticket expectedTicket = ticket.cloneWithNewId(1L);`?

Comment: @ThomasKläger, not sure that I understand... Ticket is the declared type and it does not have cloneWithNewId method in it.

Comment: Is the `ticket` variable a `Ticket` or a `TicketImpl`?

Comment: It is Ticket, not TicketImpl. Added more to description:
"Required type:Ticket. Provided: EntityId"

Comment: @user207421, I changed return type in TicketImpl:
TicketImpl cloneWithNewId(long id) {...}
The error has not changed.

Comment: I disagree with the first comment - this is a valid use of a covariant return type. Can you provide the unit test that produces the error?

Comment: The unit test:
    @Test
    void shouldBookTicket() {
        Ticket ticket = new TicketImpl(7L, 8L, Ticket.Category.PREMIUM, 21);
        Ticket expectedTicket = ticket.cloneWithNewId(1L);

The error is produced by last line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the unit test, you are not invoking the method with the narrowed return type.

The compiler raises an error here, because the return type of `Ticket#cloneWithNewId(long)` is `EntityId`, as it is inherited from `EntityId`. Note that, when confronted with a compiler error, it does not make sense to argue about a specific `TicketImpl` instance, as you are not in a runtime. Instead only the declared type of each local variable is relevant.

This is also why

```
public interface Ticket {
    @Override
    public Ticket cloneWithNewId(long id);
}
```

will fix the compiler error.

Another possible fix is to change the unit test to

```
@Test
void shouldBookTicket() {
    TicketImpl ticket = new TicketImpl(7L, 8L, Ticket.Category.PREMIUM, 21);
    Ticket expectedTicket = ticket.cloneWithNewId(1L);
//...
}
```

as that will "point" the compiler to the method declaration in `TicketImpl`, whose return type is narrowed to `Ticket`.

Comment: Thank you, that was simple indeed, I probably haven't woken up to miss that ))